# Close the activity before open it

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk

I'm using an intent to send information to my social network applications in Android and post a message in them.

The problem is if the application is already open when I try to call them, it just opens it without sending the message. Otherwise, if the application was closed and I call this intent, it opens the application and sends the message correctly.

In the intent, I can use the flag: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and it closes the activity I'm about to call before opening it. It's perfect, it solves the problem.

But... this flag is just avaible for Android 3.0 (API LEVEL 11) and my application aims Android 2.1 at least.

Is there any other option to do something like this?

Here is my code:

```
for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList) 
    {   
        if((app.activityInfo.name).contains(socialNetwork.value)) 
        {
            installed = true;

            try
            {
                final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                context.startActivity(shareIntent);
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
       }
    }
```

**I want to remove "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK " but have the same effect.**

Comment: You can putExtras in the intent/bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when you send the intent and the app was open in the background, it is just reorder to the front? If so, try setting the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) flag instead. It will open the activity, even if the same activity is open in the background, so you will have two instances of it

Comment: I don't want to open an instance in background because then the intent doesn't work correctly. I need to close that instance before open it, to start from the beggining. I added the code I'm using.